# Cocoa encrypt with public key, not x509 certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, encryption, rsa

The Cocoa `SecCertificateCreateWithData` method accept a DER-encoded X.509 certificate as it's input, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCertificateCreateWithData

But I just want to encrypt with exactly ONLY the public key, no other unneccessary things. Can I do this with Cocoa? Maybe using openssl may work, but I will consider only Cocoa before it couldn't work.

Comment: Is this a preference or a requirement? if its a preference I would highly recommend against trying to do this manually and sticking to the easy way using the built in apple stuff

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin It is a requirement, the server returns ONLY the public key, no other things.

Comment: Ok, I had a very similar issue. I tired using openSSL and spent a few days pulling my hair out. Thankfully the server was being developed by us also. I was able to make it a requirement for the server to return the cert file, which is much more standard, meaning I could use the apple stuff. I spent quite a while trying to find a way to do this with the apple crypto library and couldn't find a solution

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Thanks for your comments. Now I try to figure out how to build a self-signed certificate from an existing public key, still trying and searching.